# Extract URLs with regex into a new data frame column

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I want to use a regex to extract all URLs from text in a dataframe, into a new column. I have some older code that I have used to extract keywords, so I'm looking to adapt the code for a regex. I want to save a regex as a string variable and apply here:

```
data$ContentURL <- apply(sapply(regex, grepl, data$Content, fixed=FALSE), 1, function(x) paste(selection[x], collapse=','))
```

It seems that `fixed=FALSE` should tell `grepl` that its a regular expression, but R doesn't like how I am trying to save the regex as:

```
regex <- "http.*?1-\\d+,\\d+"
```

My data is organized in a data frame like this:

```
data <- read.table(text='"Content"     "date"   
 1     "a house a home https://www.foo.com"     "12/31/2013"
 2     "cabin ideas https://www.example.com in the woods"     "5/4/2013"
 3     "motel is a hotel"   "1/4/2013"', header=TRUE)
```

And would hopefully look like:

```
                                           Content       date              ContentURL
1               a house a home https://www.foo.com 12/31/2013     https://www.foo.com
2 cabin ideas https://www.example.com in the woods   5/4/2013 https://www.example.com
3                                 motel is a hotel   1/4/2013
```

Comment: For R, the entire regex must go in a character variable. Where did you get the idea that `\\<` and `\\>` would be parsed?

Comment: You are playing with fire if you use `grep` to regex on an html document

Comment: Perhaps, showing us the data and what you are trying to extract will also help out.

Comment: All urls or a certain url?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I want to extract all urls.

Comment: thanks for sticking with my question! I think all pieces of the puzzle are up there now. I'll try and make it more clear. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Hadleyverse solution (`stringr` package) with a decent URL pattern:

```
library(stringr)

url_pattern <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+"

data$ContentURL <- str_extract(data$Content, url_pattern)

data

##                                            Content       date              ContentURL
## 1               a house a home https://www.foo.com 12/31/2013     https://www.foo.com
## 2 cabin ideas https://www.example.com in the woods   5/4/2013 https://www.example.com
## 3                                 motel is a hotel   1/4/2013                    <NA>
```

You can use `str_extract_all` if there are multiples in `Content`, but that will involve some extra processing on your end afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using the `qdapRegex` library:

```
library(qdapRegex)
data[["url"]] <- unlist(rm_url(data[["Content"]], extract=TRUE))
data

##                                            Content       date                     url
## 1               a house a home https://www.foo.com 12/31/2013     https://www.foo.com
## 2 cabin ideas https://www.example.com in the woods   5/4/2013 https://www.example.com
## 3                                 motel is a hotel   1/4/2013                    <NA>
```

To see the regular expression used by the function (as `qdapRegex` aims to help analyze and educate about regexs) you can use the `grab` function with the function name prefixed with `@`:

```
grab("@rm_url")

## [1] "(http[^ ]*)|(ftp[^ ]*)|(www\\.[^ ]*)"
```

`grepl` tells you a logical output of yes this string contains or no it does not.  `grep` tells you the indexes or gives the values but values are the whole string nut the substring you want.

So to pass this regex along to base or the **stringi** package (**qdapRegex** wraps **stingi** for extraction) you could do:

```
regmatches(data[["Content"]], gregexpr(grab("@rm_url"), data[["Content"]], perl = TRUE))

library(stringi)
stri_extract(data[["Content"]], regex=grab("@rm_url"))
```

I'm sure there's a **stringr** approach too but am not familiar with the package.

Answer (score 0):

Split on space then find "http":

```
data$ContentURL <- unlist(sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Content), split = " "),
                                 function(i){
                                   x <- i[ grepl("http", i)]
                                   if(length(x) == 0) x <- NA
                                   x
                                 }))


data
#                                            Content       date              ContentURL
# 1               a house a home https://www.foo.com 12/31/2013     https://www.foo.com
# 2 cabin ideas https://www.example.com in the woods   5/4/2013 https://www.example.com
# 3                                 motel is a hotel   1/4/2013                    <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package *unglue* :

```
library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(data,Content, "{=.*?}{url=http[^ ]*}{=.*?}",remove = FALSE)
#>                                            Content       date                       url
#> 1               a house a home https://www.f00.com 12/31/2013 1     https://www.f00.com
#> 2 cabin ideas https://www.example.com in the woods   5/4/2013 2 https://www.example.com
#> 3                                 motel is a hotel   1/4/2013 3                    <NA>
```

- `{=.*?}` matches anything and is not assigned to an extracted column so the lhs of `=` is empty
- `{url=http[^ ]*}` matches something that starts with `http` and is followed by non spaces, as the lhs is `url` it is extracted into `url`

Ps: I manually changed `foo` into `f00` in my answer because of SO restrictions