# removing url with format www in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, data-cleaning

I need to remove some urls from a dataframe. So far I have been able to eliminate those with the pattern  `http://`. However, there are still some websites in my corpus with the format  `www.stackoverflow.com` or `stackoverflow.org`

**Here is my code**

```
#Sample of text
   test_text <- c("la primera posibilidad real de acabar con la violencia del país es www.jorgeorlandomelo.com y luego desatar")

#Trying to remove the website with no results
test_text <- gsub("www[.]//([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),])//[.]com", "", test_text)
```

## The outcome should be

```
   test_text
"la primera posibilidad real de acabar con la violencia del país es y luego desatar"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract URLs with regex into a new data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496538/extract-urls-with-regex-into-a-new-data-frame-column)

Comment: @cory, as I mentioned in my question, I have been able to remove those websites starting with  `http://` The example you are sharing is for achieving that purpose. In this question I am asking how should I deal with websites as `www.stackoverflow` or `www.stackoverflow.org`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following regex removes the test url.

```
test_text <- c("la primera posibilidad real de acabar con la violencia del país es www.jorgeorlandomelo.com y luego desatar",
               "bla1 bla2 www.stackoverflow.org etc",
               "this that www.nameofthewebiste.com one more"
)

gsub("(^[^w]*)www\\.[^\\.]*\\.[[:alpha:]]{2,3}(.*$)", "\\1\\2", test_text)
#[1] "la primera posibilidad real de acabar con la violencia del país es  y luego desatar"
#[2] "bla1 bla2  etc"                                                                     
#[3] "this that  one more"
```

Comment: Would this regex remove every website with the format `www.nameofthewebiste.com` ? Additionally,  how can I modify the code to also delete websites with the format `.org` and `.co`. Thanks!

Comment: @JoseDavid Yes it would, see the edit. It removes *any* website with 2 or 3 letters after the dot.